# how to stop numbers to be formatted as telephone number on a blackberry browser

Tags: blackberry

I am developing web pages for blackberry 8700. I have few 5 digits or sometimes 10 digits numbers in my page. These number are displayed or formatted as mobile numbers and on click of the same a telephone call is initiated. Please let me know how to stop that and display that number as a string on the blackberry browser. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [BlackBerry Knowledge Base](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800878/800733/How_To_-_Disable_Phone_Number_Hyperlinking_in_the_BlackBerry_Browser.html?nodeid=1254068&vernum=0):

The BlackBerry® Browser underlines phone numbers and allows a BlackBerry smartphone user to automatically place a call from within the BlackBerry Browser; however, it can sometimes mistake other numbers for being a phone number and underline or hyperlink this number.

To disable all phone numbers from being hyperlinked in an HTML or Wireless Markup Language (WML) page, add the following tag to the source code:

```
<meta name="x-rim-auto-match" http-equiv="x-rim-auto-match" forua="true" content="none"/>
```

Comment: that link is broken (3+ years later), but pretty sure this is the same one, different url http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Disable-phone-number-hyperlinking-in-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/445807